# Is it semi-supervised learning if my training images are all "unanomalous"?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, anomaly-detection

If I train a anomaly detection framework on a training dataset that consists of unanomalous images, so that it can detect anomalies in the test dataset if for example the reconstruction error is very high.

Does the training dataset therefore count as labeled, since all images are unanomalous? If yes, would this be semi-supervised learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might consider it a "one class" problem. The distinction between supervised or unsupervised in that case is maybe not so relevant.

Semi-supervised refers to the case where you have a large amount of unlabeled data, and a smaller amount of labeled data - both used for training. Usually in a way where one uses the smaller labeled data to label the larger unlabeled data (label propagation). That is not the case for a one-class anomaly detection training setup, so I would not call it semi-supervised.